# "Can't call method "category" without a package or object reference at" in perl

Tags: perl, object, methods

I can't seem to figure this out, and I couldn't find anything online. So here is my code:

Type.pm

```
use constant {
UNABLE_TO_PING_SWITCH_ERROR => {
         category => 'Connection Error',
         template => "Could not ping switch %s in %s seconds.",
         context => [ qw(switch_ip  timeout) ],
         tt => {template => 'disabled'},
         fatal => 1,
         wiki_page => 'www.error-fix.com/',
     },
};
```

Error.pm
The new method outputs the error message in the format shown in stringify

```
# Method for creating error message
  sub new {
      my ( $class, $error, %args ) = @_;
      # Initialize error with data
      my $self = $error;
      # If the error contains context parameters... Insert parameters into string template
      if(%args) {
          foreach my $key (@{ $self->{context} } ) {
              # And take the ones we need
              $self->{args}->{$key} = $args{$key};
          }
          my @template_args = map { $self->{args}->{$_} } @{ $self->{context} };
          # map/insert arguments into context hash and insert into string template
          $self->{message} = sprintf ($self->{template}, @template_args);
          $self->stringify;
          }
          return bless $self, $class;
      }
      else { return bless $self, $class; }
  }

stringify {
    my ($self) = @_;
    return sprintf("%s : %s\nMore info: %s", $self->category, $self->message, $self->wiki_page);
}
```

This is the error I am receiving.

```
#   Failed test 'Return the correct message'
    #   at t/67_Error.t line 47.
    #          got: undef
    #     expected: 'Could not ping switch 192.192.0.0 in 30 seconds.'
Can't call method "category" without a package or object reference at Error.pm line 77.
```

Line 77 is the return statement inside stringify.

If you need any more info or code let me know.

## Attempt solution (sof far)

```
 sub new {
    my ( $class, $error, %args ) = @_;
    # Initialize error with data
    my $self = $error;
    # If the error contains context parameters... Insert parameters into string template
        if($self eq 'HASH' && %args) {
            bless $self, $class;
            foreach my $key (@{ $self->{context} } ) {
                 # bless $self, $class;
                 # And take the ones we need
                 $self->{args}->{$key} = $args{$key};
            }
            my @template_args = map { $self->{args}->{$_} } @{ $self->{context} };
            # map/insert arguments into context hash and insert into string template
            $self->{message} = sprintf ($self->{template}, @template_args);
            my $output = _stringify($self->category, $self->message, $self->wiki_page);
            bless $output, $class;
            return $output;
            }
            else { return bless $self, $class; }
   }
```

## Test Code : t/67_Error.t

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use lib ('./t/lib');
use strict;
no strict 'refs';
use warnings;

use ASC::Builder::Error;
use ASC::Builder::Error::Type;
use ASC::Builder::Error::Type 'code';
use Test::More;
use Test::Exception;
use LWP::Simple 'head'; # Used to test if wiki link is giving a response

subtest 'Functionality of Error' => sub {

    my $example_error = {
        category => 'Connection Error',
        template => 'Could not ping switch %s in %s seconds.',
        context => [ qw(switch_ip  timeout) ],
        tt => {template => 'disabled'},
        fatal => 1,
        wiki_page => 'http://www.error-fix.com',
    };
    # Correct case
    {
        my $error = ASC::Builder::Error->new( $example_error, timeout => 30, switch_ip => '192.192.0.0' );

        isa_ok ($error, 'ASC::Builder::Error');

        can_ok ($error, 'category');
        is ($error->category(), 'Connection Error', 'Return the correct category');

        can_ok ($error, 'template');
        is ($error->template(), 'Could not ping switch %s in %s seconds.', 'Return the correct category');

        can_ok ($error, 'tt');
        is ($error->tt(), 'disabled', 'Return the correct tt template');

        can_ok ($error, 'context');
        is_deeply($error->context(), ['switch_ip', 'timeout'], 'Return the correct context params');

        can_ok ($error, 'is_fatal');
        ok($error->is_fatal(), 'Return the correct value');

        can_ok ($error, 'message');
        is ($error->message(), 'Could not ping switch 192.192.0.0 in 30 seconds.', 'Return the correct message');
        can_ok ($error, 'stringify');
        is ($error->stringify(), "Connection Error : Could not ping switch 192.192.0.0 in 30 seconds.\nMore info: http://www.error-fix.com", 'stringify creates the correct message');

};

    # Too many arguments (this is okay)
    lives_ok( sub { ASC::Builder::Error->new($example_error, timeout => 1, switch_ip => 2, extra => 3 ) }, 'Creating with too many arguments lives. (allows for additional context          string to be added in the code)' );
    };

    subtest 'Correctness of Type.pm' => sub {

# These test cases contain all the errors from Type.pm
    my @test_cases = (
       {
            name => 'UNABLE_TO_PING_SWITCH_ERROR',
            args => {
                switch_ip => '192.192.0.0',
                timeout => 30,
            },
            message => 'Could not ping switch 192.192.0.0 in 30 seconds.',
        },
    );


    foreach my $t (@test_cases) {
        subtest $t->{name} => sub {
            no strict 'refs'; # Because we need to use variable to get to a constant
            ASC::Builder::Error::Type->import($t->{name});

            # Create the Error object from the test data
            # Will also fail if the name was not exported by Type.pm
            my $error;
            lives_ok( sub { $error = ASC::Builder::Error->new( &{ $t->{name} },%{ $t->{args} }) }, 'Error can be created');

            # See if it has the right values
            is ($error->message, $t->{message}, 'Error message is correct');

            # Using LWP::Simple to check if the wiki page link is not broken
            #ok head($error->wiki_page); #CANT'T GET THIS TEST TO WORK

        }
    }
};
done_testing;
```

## UPDATE: Message method:

It is just a getter.

```
 sub message {
        return shift->{message};
 }
```

Comment: Why are you calling `stringify` inside your constructor?

Comment: Please show the actual test code that triggers this issue.

Comment: ok will add test code .

Comment: so it appears as though it's the call to `message()` that's causing the issue. Can you show us that sub?

Comment: @stevieb added message stub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In short**: (1) Keyword `sub` is missing in front of `stringify` (2) Once that's resolved we see that an unblessed `$self` attempts to call methods (3) Finally, there is no method `category`

---

(1) The absence of `sub` keyword triggers behavior that throws off diagnostics. The `stringify { ... }` is simply called as a class method, formally being passed a hashref.  Of course, nothing is right with that hashref and we get the early error, identifying it as bogus.  From [perldiag](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html)

> Can't call method "%s" without a package or object reference
> (F) You used the syntax of a method call, but the slot filled by the object reference or package name contains an expression that returns a defined value which is neither an object reference nor a package name. Something like this will reproduce the error:

> ```
> $BADREF = 42;
> ```

```
process $BADREF 1,2,3;
$BADREF->process(1,2,3);
```

The call `$self->stringify` has nothing to do with it, and is never executed since this is a fatal error.  (The exact error message was different for me under v5.10)

(2) When `sub` keyword is put in its place, we get to the problem: `$self` invokes a method before being `bless`-ed.  This was observed by [ThisSuitIsBlackNot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/176646/thissuitisblacknot) in a comment as well. Now there is no need for speculation of why that even works but we get the expected error

```
Can't call method "stringify" on unblessed reference at ErrorPack.pm ...
```

(3) When we first `bless` the hashref before calling methods on it, we get

```
Can't locate object method "category" via package "ErrorPack" at ErrorPack.pm ...
```

As expected, since `$self` is now an object and there is indeed no method "category". This is fixed by changing calls in `printf` so to derefence a hashref, not call methods (by adding curlies). Also noted in the answer by [bipll](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2749717/bipll).

I don't know how these changes play along with poster's intentions, but with all that

**File ErrorPack.pm**

```
package ErrorPack;

use warnings;
use strict;

# Method for creating error message
sub new {
    my ( $class, $error, %args ) = @_; 
    # Initialize error with data
    my $self = $error;
    bless $self, $class;
    # If the error contains context parameters... [...]
    if (%args) {
        foreach my $key (@{ $self->{context} } ) { 
            # And take the ones we need
            $self->{args}->{$key} = $args{$key};
        }   
        my @template_args = map { $self->{args}->{$_} } @{ $self->{context} };
        # map/insert arguments into context hash and insert into string template
        $self->{message} = sprintf ($self->{template}, @template_args);
        $self->stringify;
    }   
    return $self;
}

sub stringify {
    my ($self) = @_; 
    return sprintf("%s : %s\nMore info: %s", $self->{category}, 
        $self->{message}, $self->{wiki_page});
}
sub prn { print "$_[0]->{category}\n" }
1;
```

If there are any reasons to *not* make `$self` an object before `%args` processing, issue `bless $self, $class;` before the call to `stringify`
and then `return $self;`.

The script with **main::**

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use ErrorPack;

# Taken from testing code that is now posted
my $err = {
    category => 'Connection Error',
    template => "Could not ping switch %s in %s seconds.",
    context => [ qw(switch_ip  timeout) ],
    tt => {template => 'disabled'},
    fatal => 1,
    wiki_page => 'www.error-fix.com/',
};  

my $eobj = ErrorPack->new($err, timeout => 30, switch_ip => '192.192.0.0');
$eobj->prn();
```

This prints a line `Connection Error`, the `$eobj` can be directly queried for keys, etc.

Comment: Would it be possible to have it so that the new method (when called) would print out the values instead of having to explicitly call prn() ?

Comment: That was a typo for the stringify. Sorry

Comment: @PaulRussell  Yes, you can print from the package file as you please.  So you can add printing statements to `new`, and they will run when `new` is called so whenever an object is created. Remember that before `bless` statement executes (in `new`) the `$self` isn't an object yet and so you can't call methods on it. You can pull data out of it though, by merely derefencing its keys.  (I added a separate toy method just to demonstrate that it all works.  While you may wish to actually have a method that prints all data for an object, just so.)

Comment: @PaulRussell  Yeah, I supposed that it was a typo or such.  The funny bit is that thr particular error that was triggered (because of how such code is interpreted) confused the matters.

Answer (score 0):

```
return sprintf("%s : %s\nMore info: %s", $self->category, $self->message, $self->wiki_page);
```

Here the code looks like you're invoking methods called `category`, `message` and `wiki_page` on `$self`. You should put them in braces if they are actually hash keys.

Comment: They probably should be invoked as methods outside of the constructor to keep things encapsulated (although it's not clear if the OP has actually implemented any methods). The OP's error happens because `$self` is an unblessed hashref, not an object, when they call `$self->stringify`.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot how does it even manage to get called, then?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, the constant hash of the topmost code snippets contains `category` and `wiki_page` as keys, so I thought...

Comment: @hobbs Oops, good call. They must not be calling `new`, since that would give a (different) fatal error.